# Vaadin Grid Column setMaximumWidth ignored

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I have the following code running where myGridExample is a Vaadin 8 grid object.

```
           this.myGridExample
                    .addColumn(MapQueryService.RowResult::getFacilityType)
                    .setMinimumWidth(130)
                    .setWidth(160)
                    .setMaximumWidth(170)
                    .setCaption("Facility Type");
```

The setMaximumWidth(170) does not appear to do anything. however .setMinimumWidth(130) works as expected.  Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug :)

Answer (score 2):

From [Vaadin8-docs](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.0/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html#setMaximumWidth-double-):

> [setMaximumWidth](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.0/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html#setMaximumWidth-double-)
>
> Sets the maximum width for this column. 
>   This defines the maximum
>   allowed pixel width of the column **when it is set to expand**.
>
> ...
>
> See Also:
>   [setExpandRatio(int)](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.0/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html#setExpandRatio-int-)

If it's about [setMinimumWidth](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.0/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html#setMinimumWidth-double-) - it also works only with expanding. I made some mensuration in your gif and it looks like your minimumWidth of resizing is **~110px** (assuming that column at gif start position has 160px width). So it's probably adjusts by itself to longest column value.

Workaround for you:

```
grid.addColumnResizeListener(event -> {
   Grid.Column c = event.getColumn();
   if(c.getWidth() > c.getMaximumWidth())
      c.setWidth(c.getMaximumWidth());
   if(c.getWidth() < c.getMinimumWidth())
      c.setWidth(c.getMinimumWidth());
});
```